# Remove Weekday From ToLongDate()

Tags: ssrs-2008, date-format

I would like to display a date like...

```
=Now.ToLongDateString()
```

BUT without the weekday. So the expression would produce June 21 2011. Not Tuesday, June 21 2011. Is this possible? I don't want the format MM/DD/YY. I would rather have June 21 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an expression that works. This is here for others to use.

```
=FORMAT(Now,"MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

I don't like answering my own questions because most here think its a reputation point thing (which its not) SO, If anyone else provides an answer that is more helpful or is "neater", I will toggle off my checkmark and mark yours. Otherwise, I'll leave this up so others can use the answer as per Meta.